# How to write LSB init.d scripts that can run multiple instances of the same service?

Tags: init.d, rc, lsb

Here is the problem I have: I do have to run multiple instances of several services on the same machine and I want to be able to re-use the init.d scripts.

You can see here an example of service script for jira:
https://github.com/pycontribs/phoebian/blob/master/etc/init.d/jira

This was is self-aware of itself and assumes that the name of the instance is the name of the script.

This works quite well as it allows me to create symlinks ini init.d so I do not replicate the scripts.

Still there is one issue with the `Provides` line:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        jira
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $ssh $remote_fs postgresql
# Required-Stop:    $local_fs $network $ssh $remote_fs postgresql
# Default-Start:    3 4 5
# Default-Stop:        0 1 2 6
# Short-Description:    Jira
### END INIT INFO
#chkconfig: 2345 80 05
```

It seems that I cannot use the script name there and for this reason some tools are not working as expected, like `rcconfig`.

Any ideas, places where I can raise a feature request, alternatives? Remember, I do not want to have to copy the init.d scripts, because I will end-up having them out-of-sync.